# How can I save a Crystal Reports subreport into a separate file using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I tried to open a Crystal Reports report using Visual Studio 2012.  The piece I wanted to modify is in a subreport contained within the main report file.  (I didn't know that could be done.  I thought subreports were always separate files.)  While I can edit the subreport, I would prefer to save it into a separate file so that I can reuse it in a new report.  However, there is no option for saving a subreport.

I guessed that it was because I was using old program, so I downloaded the latest Visual Studio integration pack, installed it, and tried to edit my report in Visual Studio 2017.  Still no luck.

A web search showed me that some people have a "save subreport as..." option someplace, but I do not see it.  Am I doing something wrong, or missing something obvious?  Is this a feature that is only enabled if I have a paid version of Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's not available in Crystal Reports for VS.